# How to check if value is numpy number or python primitive

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `value` variable and it can be either

-- numpy number

-- string

-- python primitive -- float or int

How do I identify the type? Especially if the number is numpy number or python primitive number.

When I try to do the following in python interpreter

```
np.issubdtype(10, np.number)
```

I get

```
 arg1 = dtype(arg1).type
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Thanks!

Comment: `issubdtype` compares `dtypes`; it isn't a `isinstance` kind of test.  Look at its examples.

Answer (score 3):

Have you try like this.

```py
isintance(10, (int, float, str, np.number))
```

Answer (score 2):

According numpy docs --> https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.issubdtype.html

Arguments for `np.issubdtype` function should be a `dtypes` or its string representation but not an actual values.

So you can try like this:

```
np.issubdtype(type(10), np.number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should your variable be `A`, using `type(A)` should give you your answer.

For example, if you have

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([3, 4, 5])
```

`type(A)`should give you `numpy.ndarray`as answer. Similarly, `type(234)` simply returns `int`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to find the type of the variable, would type(var) just work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type() method in Python.

```
>>> r = np.float32(1.0)
>>> type(r).__name__
'numpy.float32'

>>> s = '1.0'
>>> type(s).__name__
'str'

>>> t = 1.0 
>>> type(t).__name__
'float'
```